# Run function only after event handler triggered

Tags: jquery, settimeout

I need to continuously fetch new data every 5 minutes, but only if the user is active on the page.

Here's my progress/thoughts so far:

1. When the document is loaded, get the data and use the setTimeout method to essentially sleep a function for 5 min.
2. After 5 min, the function will run, but only update the data if the user mouseovers a section of the page.

   ```
   setTimeout(getData, 10000) // Shortened time for testing purposes
   function getData(){
       $('#feed').mouseover(function(){
           $('#feed').fadeOut();
           Get the feed
           setTimeout(getData, 10000);
       });
   }
   ```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: You will attach the event handler over and over again. That means you will **add** an event handler every time....

Comment: @Felix - +1, yeah I unbound the event handler.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a better way but for this example you will need to `unbind` the `.mouseover` like so:

```
setTimeout(getData, 10000) // Shortened time for testing purposes
function getData(){
    $('#feed').mouseover(function(){
        $('#feed').fadeOut();
        Get the feed
        $(this).unbind('mouseover');
        setTimeout(getData, 10000);
    });
}
```

Otherwise the event will still be bound and you'll keep calling the feed regardless of the timeout

Comment: Yeah, I just crossed that issue as we speak. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Jacob's answer, you could use a flag and after some time, set it to `false`. You could keep your function that gets the data running in background and check that flag:

```
var active = true;
var current_timeout = null;

function idle() {
    active = false;
    current_timeout = null; 
}


$('#feed').mousemove(function(){ 
    // maybe another event that does not 
    // constantly fire (but often enough) is enough

    active = true;
    if(current_timeout !== null) {
        window.clearTimeout(current_timeout);
    }
    timeout = window.setTimeout(idle, 180000); // mark not active after 3 minutes
});

window.setInterval(function() {
    if(active) {
        //get data
    }
), 300000);
```

I'm not sure though if it not too unnecessary to have the interval run although the user is not on the page (although it won't do anything as long as `active` is false). You have to test that.